# How to replace only first instance of text in notepad++ in multiple files?

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I'm working on updating a website with a few changes and I've managed to do most of the changes to multiple files using standard find and replace searches. There is just one error left over from my f/r that I need to fix but it occurs several times throughout the document and I want to replace only the first instance, the only time it's an error.

```
 </div><div class="boxb">
```

That occurs seven times in each file, only the FIRST time I need to remove the trailing, closing DIV. All the others are correct.

I gather I need to use the Regular Expression mode but I've tried a few examples and they either don't work or they still replace all occurences, not just the first as I require.

Also to be clear, I don't know if it makes a difference, but I need to do this to multiple files, so using 'Find In Files' rather than just 'Replace'.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way is to match the whole content of the file, then replace back the parts that you still want to keep. This ensure that the whole file produces exactly 1 match. This method is not yet tested, but it might be slow on big file.

1. Just write your regex as per normal, then add `(.*?)` in front and `(.*)` at the back:

   ```
   (.*?)pattern(.*)
   ```

   You should test with `(.*?)pattern` on a few files to make sure that it matches the first instance of the text you want to remove.
2. Check the checkbox ***"`.` matches newline"***.
3. **The replacement string** may vary depending on your regex, but the idea is to capture the parts that you want to keep in the regex of step 1 and replace them back in this step.

   For example, if you want to remove anything that matches `pattern`, then use `$1$2` as replacement string.

Comment: I probably should have said that I have no experience of regex, I only mentioned it as I thought it was possibly what was needed.

Answer (score 0):

The text you give appears to be fixed, so a regular expression is not needed to find it. The replace part of **Find in files** replaces *all* occurrences in each file. Assuming the number of files is not huge, I would suggest using the **Find all** button on **Find in files** and then manually changing them one by one. If the number of files is large then Notepad++ is probably not be the best tool to make the changes.

For other options consider programs such as Perl or Awk; with these the task would be simple.

Comment: Number of files is circa 150 so no, not something I want to do manually, that's why I was making the changes with F+R in the first place. I'm open to using other programs if someone could walk me through it but surely it must be possible with Notepad++?