# Adding header to multiple files

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-editor

I have a bunch of files that are saved in a .pg format. I can open and edit them using notepad++.

I want to prepend in every file the same header. Is there a regular expression that could select all text in a file so that I could search and replace to add my header?

So that

```
Some text in file 1

Some text in file 2
```

...
becomes

becomes

```
Header
Some text in file 1

Header
Some text in file 2
```

...

Comment: looks like something you could do using cat/type - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows

Comment: `\A`(beginning of string) you can prepend your `Header` text. Search-replace on `\A` and add `Header\n`. This might not work in all editors tho, so I'm not sure if it will work on a file's contents.

Comment: Both answers below add header before each lines yeah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace only first instance of text in notepad++ in multiple files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848690/how-to-replace-only-first-instance-of-text-in-notepad-in-multiple-files)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work,

Regex:

```
(?s)^
```

Replacement string:

```
Header\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Find:

`(.*)^`

Replace:

`THIS IS THE FOOTER`

Be sure you check the . matches newline box in the Search Mode box (as well as selecting Regular expression).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this search/replace:

```
search: ^
replace: Header\n
```

Comment: This adds Header before every line of every file.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: You must use a single replace, not a replaceall.

Comment: To search and replace in all files in a given folder, there seems to be only a replace all with notepad++.